# A class that inherits from two classes in c++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

Assuming that I have got a class *Alcohol* and it has got two derived classes: *Wine* and *Beer*. What happens if I will make then a class *Cider* that inherits from *Wine* and *Beer* as well?

How many copies of *Alcohol* will appear in *Cider* class?

I know that it can be done with virtual inheritance and without it but what will be the difference?

Comment: Obviously, with that much alcohol, you'll see double, and there will be *two* bases.

Comment: Independent from the answer: This is a bad idea. Cider is neither wine nor beer, so it should not inherit from either of those.

Comment: A google search on "diamond inheritance virtual" will turn up plenty of articles explaining exactly this. And, BTW, both Kerrek SB and Baum mit Augen are correct.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: well... it's cheap as beer but looks posh as wine, so I can see how one might get there.

Comment: you should use a language that allows you to _mixin_ your drinks... ;)

Comment: @BaummitAugen: The metaphor is rapidly going downhill! Now `cheap` is-an `Alcohol`? I think we went too far in a few places...

Comment: @KerrekSB Oh no! It's a slippery slope I guess. And alcohol is dangerous too.

Comment: Also, beer and wine are (usually) alcololic drinks that contain a cretain amount of alcohol, but they are not alcohol. So the name of the base class is poorly chosen.

Comment: @BaummitAugen _" And alcohol is dangerous too."_ That's why I'm preferring THC mostly. But there are edge cases too: It seems that mixtures of THC and CBD can be dangerous, but  at least that doesn't come from mixing the same bases.

Answer (score 13):

Non-virtual inheritance:

```
struct Beer : Alcohol {};
struct Wine : Alcohol {};           // I'll have what he's having!
```

```
Alcohol   Alcohol                   // ...whe-ere'sh my... bayshe clashhh... hic
   ^         ^
   |         |
 Beer       Wine
    ^       ^
     \     /
      \   /
      Cider
```

Virtual inheritance:

```
struct Beer : virtual Alcohol {};   // virtual = doesn't get you drunk
struct Wine : virtual Alcohol {};
```

```
     Alcohol                        // you can see clearly now
     ^     ^
    /       \
 Beer       Wine
    ^       ^
     \     /
      \   /
      Cider
```

In the non-virtual case, there are two disctinct base subobjects. Let's get at them:

```
Cider x;
Alcohol & a1 = static_cast<Beer&>(x);
Alcohol & a2 = static_cast<Wine&>(x);

assert(std::addressof(a1) != std::addressof(a2));
```

Comment: @siema: As the picture attempts to show: two. One on the left, and one on the right.

Comment: upvoting just for the comedy diagram comments! :)

Comment: would it be the same will classes like with structs?

Comment: @siema struct are just classes with everything public

Comment: @siema: `struct` is a keyword. It's not otherwise a tangible thing. Both `class` and `struct` are valid class keys that introduce class types (as is `union`).

Comment: @KerrekSB Cool, that answer bangs. Incenting another spliff right now ;-) ... (alcoholics pfffft ...)